# Angular two ng-repeat in one table make duplicate

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a new project and I'm really stuck in that table.

There are two list of objects: `settingtime` and `settings`, 
and I want to put them together in one cell with ng-if.
but when I do that they are duplicate and just make more cells.

*one thing is there are 7 tables for each day. this is an example for sunday.

The Ng-if that I want to check is when the `settingTime.id` is equal to the `setting.settingTimeid`
**and while they are equal put them together in one cell.**

[image: enter link description here]

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
<tbody ng-repeat="setting in settings">
<tr ng-repeat="settingtime in settingtimes | orderBy:'time' | filter:by_shiftDay" ng-if="settingtime.shiftDay=='SUNDAY'">
    <td ng-if="setting.settingTimeId==settingtime.id">
    {{settingtime.shiftDay}}
    </br>
    {{settingtime.time}}
    </br>
    SettingTimeId: {{setting.settingTimeId}} {{settingtime.id}}
    </br>
    Role:{{setting.role}}
    </br>
    WorkerAmount:{{setting.workerAmount}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="editsettingtime" ng-click="EditSettingTime(settingtime.id)">Edit</button>
    </br><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getAllRoles(); toggleRight(); saveSettingTime(settingtime.id); showAddSetting()">AddSetting</button>
     </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

---

```
settingtime: [
    {"id":2,"shiftDay":"MONDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"12:00"},
    {"id":202,"shiftDay":"SATURDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"06:00"},
    {"id":5,"shiftDay":"FRIDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"17:30"},
    {"id":4,"shiftDay":"SUNDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"19:00"}, 
    {"id":302,"shiftDay":"WEDNESDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"15:00"}, 
    {"id":3,"shiftDay":"MONDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"06:00"}, 
    {"id":1,"shiftDay":"SUNDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"15:00"}, 
    {"id":101,"shiftDay":"TUESDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"10:00"}, 
    {"id":201,"shiftDay":"THURSDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"12:00"}, 
    {"id":6,"shiftDay":"WEDNESDAY","hours":0,"minutes":0,"time":"10:00"}
]

settings: [
    {"id":2,"settingTimeId":4,"role":1,"workerAmount":1},
    {"id":4,"settingTimeId":1,"role":4,"workerAmount":3},
    {"id":1,"settingTimeId":1,"role":1,"workerAmount":1},
    {"id":3,"settingTimeId":1,"role":2,"workerAmount":2}]
```

Comment: Please provide your list objects

Comment: ng-repeat tag repeat the element where you will applied it upto the length of your provided list and your first ng-repeat repeating tbody tag instead of tr it should be on tr tag so you won't face duplication of cell. Also you have to move your ng-if from td element to tr element.

Comment: how to put 2 ng-repeats in one tr?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, will come up with proper solution

Comment: update your td tag as `<td ng-show="setting.settingTimeId==settingtime.id">` and try. You can refer my code at http://jsfiddle.net/mayurtakawale/U3pVM/49137/

Comment: still doesnt work bro :O

Comment: its the same as ng-if.. but still doesnt fix the problem of the duplicate..

Comment: have you checked this http://jsfiddle.net/mayurtakawale/U3pVM/49137/ ?

Comment: yes. should i use ur todoCtrl?

Comment: No you don't have to. Just cross check your code with mine.

Comment: i even replaced it bro and thats what happend: the same thing.(https://image.prntscr.com/image/J6XClTqsQaeP-vUPZRGSqQ.png) if u didnt understand look at the image. there are 4 rows in sunday. there are 3 of the same settingtime.. i dont want it to happen. thats happen because there are 3 different settings that related to one settingtime. and i want them to be in same one cell! u now understand?

Comment: Any more help bro?